# MVC 3 - FormsAuthentication - Can't give access to my Login action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I'm using MVC 3 and FormsAuthentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/" timeout="2880" />      
</authentication>
```

My Account/Index page displays a login page, then using Jquery, it does a post to Account/Login to authenticate the user. Here's my AccountController action which handles it:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Users = "*")]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password) {
    ...
}
```

And the Jquery which posts to it:

```
$.post("/account/login", {
                "userName": $("#userName").val(),
                "password": $("#password").val()
            }, function (data) {
...});
```

All the above works, but now I want to restrict general access to the site, so I added this to my root web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />      
</authorization>
```

And in an attempt to allow access to the Account controller, I added this:

```
<location path="~/Account">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

**Here's my problem**. I can view the login page (Account/Index), but I can't submit to Account/Login. When I watch what's going on through Fiddler, I get this text returned from the server when posting to that page:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/?ReturnUrl=%2faccount%2flogin">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

It seems that when I add "~/Account" to the full authorized user list it isn't really working like it would in a non-mvc project. Is there a special way to do this in MVC 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path to a controller is typically not referenced as a relative path. You should just be able to say location="Account", e.g.

```
<location path="Account">
```

Can't be sure that's your issue as I can't test it right now, but it could be...

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. It's always something so simple that I overlook... :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `AuthorizeAttribute` at all for the Login action. It makes no sense to require authorization for the authorization process itself.

To require authorization for all your Controllers you could create

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthorizeController : Controller 
{
}
```

and extend all your Controllers from this one except the `AccountController`.

Comment: This was helpful too - at first I didn't have the [Authorize] attribute, but I added it somewhere along the way of trying to do my own fixes for it. When I fixed the location path and removed the [AUthorize], I ended up working just fine. Wish there was a way to accept two answers...